# Is ftp connection to secure server in c++ program secure with libcurl?

Tags: ftp

Is ftp connection to secure server in c++ program secure with libcurl?I need to make a client program that will receive and write data to the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP is insecure, it transfers data, user names & passwords in the clear. Don't use it. Use either https, scp or sftp.

Comment: I don't share anything secret. To be honest, this is my first time working with hosts, databases, etc. For me, the main thing is that no one gets access to the host

Comment: A packet sniff will show usernames & passwords. If they get them, then they can access it.

Comment: login and password to access the host?

Comment: Yes!     DON'T USE FTP!

Comment: Understood. If it's easy for you, you can briefly explain or throw off links. How can I, for example, create a file on the host using https, as far as I understand, this requires some kind of software on the host?

Comment: Just google for apache/nginx upload config, which will require either of those 2 to be installed, configured and running. You are best to use scp or sftp though, as it's built-in to ssh, and you're much more likely to be running an ssh server.

Comment: FTP can be encrypted using TLS, just like HTTP. While indeed there are probably better protocols to use, what this answer says isn't really accurate.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl That is `ftps`, not `ftp`.

Comment: That's like saying that HTTPS is not HTTP. The libcurl supports FTP over TLS (aka FTPS) and that's the point here.

Comment: Ok, I was given a limited user (I only have access to a couple of folders). I connect via ftp fine, but how do I now set up a connection with ssh support. What do I need for this?